# Adobe After Effects text change using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, after-effects, lottie

I have created a video template in Adobe After Effects for the birthday wish. I want to change the inside text (Name of the birthday person) dynamically using JavaScript and export to .MP4 formate, don't want to use After Effects each time to export video.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you will ALWAYS need the After Effects machine (even when you render via Media Encoder) to create your video. So I am not sure what you mean with "not using After Effects". 
If you are a video editor you could create a MOGRT and place that in Premiere -- but then you have to open Premiere ;-) - Joke aside - than you donÄt need AE anymore and just change the name in Premiere.

For professional situations in AE you can make use of "[templater bot](https://aescripts.com/templater/)" - but this way too expensive for your private usage.

You could also export it to [XML](https://aescripts.com/xml-gibson/) or just export the text to a [spreadsheet](https://aescripts.com/text2spreadsheet/) and then change the name - but truly -- for ONE NAME this whole business is not worth it.